# Error when using source in a python Tox ini file

Tags: python-2.7, automated-tests, conda, tox

I'm trying to get Tox and Conda to play together well. Mainly because I have a lot of non-python dependencies that need to be installed and it was easy to create Conda distributions. Then I can install everything with a simple `conda install`.

However, I'm having trouble with activating the conda environment.

```
[tox]
envlist = py27

[testenv]
whitelist_externals =
    conda
    source
    py.test
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/damlarces
install_command =
    python build_env.py --conda-env {toxworkdir}/conda {packages}
commands =
    source activate {toxworkdir}/conda
    py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
```

The `python build_env.py --conda-env {toxworkdir}/conda {packages}` takes care of creating the environment (if needed), installing the packages, etc. The problem comes at the `source activate {toxworkdir}/conda` line. I get an `ERROR: InvocationError: could not find executable 'source'` error. Typing the command directly into the command-line works fine.

For those who are interested. The `build_env.py` is in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/JudoWill/70450979353fa2d12823 ... Currently its just installing Python dependencies but in its intended environment it will be installing Conda repo's that are not necessarily python libraries.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I know neither conda nor tox, but since you seem to be able to execute python scripts this way, can't you write a script to wrap that call to `source`, similar to `build_env.py`?

Comment: Tried that. Because of the way Tox works, the shell is lost between the `install_command` and the `commands` sections of the run. I've also tried to encapsulate the two `commands` into a single bash-script. This also gives and `InvocationError`.

Comment: Could you show what is inside `build_env.py`? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe You can see the `build_env.py` code here: https://gist.github.com/JudoWill/70450979353fa2d12823

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After plenty of tinkering I figured out a work-around. Its probably brittle to any changes in Tox but as long as they run tests in the order provided by `envlist` then it should work.

As suggested by @asmeurer in his answer, the trick is to somehow change the `PATH` as recognized by tox. But in order to generate the `conda/bin` I need to run `conda create`. First, I tried using the `export PATH={toxworkdir}/conda/bin:$PATH` suggested by asmeurer, but this ran into the same `InvocationError` issue just with `export` instead of `source`.

Next, I tried using the `setenv` tox section to change the path. This resulted in a chicken & egg problem. I couldn't add the `bin` directory until I ran the `conda create` command. Because of the default order of commands in Tox it doesn't seem like I can get the `setenv` to differ (or re-run) after the `install_command`.

The work-around I came up with was to create a new `env` to test against and then share this environment with the subsequent tests.

```
[tox]
envlist = setup,py27

[testenv]
whitelist_externals =
    conda
    source
    py.test

[testenv:setup]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/damlarces
commands =
    conda config --add channels judowill
    python build_env.py --conda-env {toxworkdir}/conda {packages}

[testenv:py27]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/damlarces
    PATH={toxworkdir}/conda/bin:$PATH
commands =
    {toxworkdir}/conda/bin/py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
```

This works. I'm not sure how difficult it would be to generalize this to a multiple python environment, but it works for me.

Answer (score 8):

`source` is not a command. It's a shell builtin. `source script.sh` causes `script.sh` to be run inside the current shell. This is necessary for `activate`, because it modifies the PATH, and you want those modifications to affect the shell itself (normally, when you run a script, it runs in a subshell, which has its own environment that cannot affect the calling shell's environment).

I don't know if tox supports setting environment variables in the commands. If so, you can just use

```
export PATH={toxworkdir}/conda/bin:$PATH
```

Otherwise, just use the absolute path to all your commands, like

```
{toxworkdir}/conda/bin/py.test --basetemp={envtmpdir}
```

Comment: Will that reset the path after the program runs?

Comment: `PATH` will only be set local to tox. Any time you change an environment variable in a program or a script, it only affects the environment for that program, not your shell (the exception is if you have a bash script that you call with `source`).

Comment: No dice. Now I get an invocation error on the `export` command. `ERROR: InvocationError: could not find executable 'export'`

Comment: I also tried using the `setenv` section of `tox.ini` to add the path. The problem is that when making a new run the `conda create` hasn't run yet and there's no `conda/bin` directory.

Comment: That's probably fine. The path doesn't have to exist yet for you to put it on the PATH.